# What are the cases when `return false` does not do the same thing as `e.preventDefault()`?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [JavaScript: event.preventDefault() vs return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

What are the cases when `return false` does not do the same thing as `e.preventDefault()` ?

(Note I'm not talking about jQuery events.. but JavaScript events in general)

The only situation I can think of is a `click` event on a hyperlink (if you return false in the handler you will still be redirected to the website)

Note that if its not a `click` event but a `mousedown` event on the hyperlink return false works same as `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `return false` is equivalent to `e.preventDefault();` and `e.stopPropagation();` at the same time. However, I recommend that you use the functions and the return false for future and past browser compatibility:

```
$("#something").click(function(e){
    alert("Something was clicked");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Ad@m